# comparing loop element to the name of the UIbutton pressed inside the buttonpressed function

Tags: if-statement, uibutton, swift3

I am looping through an array of string arrays.  I am comparing the element at index 0 to the title of the button pressed on the page(ideally).  But I am getting an Unresolved Identifier error, which means I am doing something wrong.  How Can I compare the element in the loop to the title of the button made programatically on the page.  Here is my code!  The issue is with the function at the bottom, in the if statement that is in the for loop.  I don't know how to say 'if this index position of the element is equal too the title of the button pressed'.

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation


class ViewController: UIViewController {

 var songArray: [Array<String>] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    //connect to website
    let url = URL(string:"*******")
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil
        {
            print("error")
        }
        else
        {
            if let content = data
            {
                do
                {
                    //download JSON data from php page, display data
                    let JSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! [[String]]
                    print(JSON)

                    //Make buttons with JSON array
                    var buttonY:  CGFloat = 20
                    for song in JSON {
                        self.songArray.append(song)
                        let SongButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: buttonY, width: 250, height: 30))
                        buttonY = buttonY + 50 // 50px spacing

                        SongButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10  //Edge formatting for buttons

                        SongButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray //Color for buttons

                        SongButton.setTitle("\(song[0])", for: UIControlState.normal) //button title

                        SongButton.titleLabel?.text = "\(song[0])"

                        SongButton.addTarget(self,action: #selector(self.songButtonPressed(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)  //button press / response

                        self.view.addSubview(SongButton)  // adds buttons to view
                    }
                }
                catch
                {

                }
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
    print(songArray)

}


func songButtonPressed(_ sender:UIButton!) { // function for buttons
    for song in songArray {
        if  "\(song[0])" == SongButton.titleLabel?.text {
            let URL = NSURL(string: "\(song[1])")
            let player = AVPlayer(url: URL! as URL)
            let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
            playerLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
            self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
            player.play()
        }
    }
}
}
```

My train of thought is to loop through the array of arrays, compare index position 0 to all button titles on the page, and if it matches, plus index position 2 into the AV player.  Thanks for any help or advice on the logic behind my code, I am a beginner and I know this level of programming is a bit over my head

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's most likely

```
for song in songArray {
   // the string interpolation "\()" is redundant 
   if song[0] == sender.titleLabel?.text { ... }
```

or maybe

```
    if song[0] == sender.title { ... }
```

`SongButton` is not related to the action method.

Comment: `for ... where` would be better here

Comment: @Alexander Yesterday I made a lot of code improving suggestions for another related question of Coder Boy (however he was using another account). All unavailingly.

Comment: @vadian you've definitely helped alot recently!  so for future reference 'sender' is what you use to reference the button pressed in general?

Comment: A target / action method passes always the UI element which triggered the action as `sender` parameter